Azure pipeline: The resource doesn't exist or the user doesn't have admin permission for all resources of that type
When I set up the docker already built plugin to set up pushing a repo to azure container i can clearly see the resource groups, acr name etc but when I save I get the error: Failed to create an app in Microsoft Entra. Error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation in Microsoft Graph Ensure that the user has permissions to create a Microsoft Entra Application. 

Hi @StefanoSKAL, Good day. Have you got a chance to check my answer below to get necessary Azure RBAC permissions to setup ACR service connections? Hope it may help resolve your issue in this post. Thx.

Based on your description, it seemed that you were trying to build and push your docker image onto ACR via the pipeline task, which referenced a new Docker Registry service connection that you tried to create.


Please be noted that when we attempt to create a Docker Registry service connection for ACR automatically, it will create a new service principal (app registration) in our Microsoft Entra Id first and then grant this principal with the AcrPush role, so that the pipeline task can authenticate against the underlying service principle of this Docker Registry service connection to push images.
Thus, the operation requires the user who creates the Docker Registry service connection to have the permission to create new app in Microsoft Entra and to setup role assignment for the ACR resource in Azure subscription. The error you encountered indicated that I didn't have the privileges to create a Microsoft Entra Application, which was only step1.

Usually, we need to be assigned with the Microsoft Entra Application Administrator/Developer and the subscription Owner/User Access Administrator roles. For this, you may reach out to the tenant global administrator and subscription owner to request necessary RBAC.
